# Redirect to checkout from custom observer

Tags: magento2, redirect, 301-redirect, redirection

I need to redirect to checkout from an observer related to the event `customer_account_edited`.

Here is my code. I've deleted a lot of rows that actually works...

Magento is doing everything well but ignore my redirection and send the user to the customer dashboard.

```
namespace Vendor\Customer\Observer;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;

class CustomerAccountEdited implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {

protected $customerRepository;
protected $helper;
protected $_objectManager = null;
protected $resultRedirectFactory;

protected $messageManager;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    \Vendor\Customer\Helper\Data $helper
){
    $this->_request             = $request;
    $this->customerRepository   = $customerRepository;
    $this->helper               = $helper;
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
    $this->messageManager               = $messageManager;

}

public function execute( \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer ){

    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__("Success message"));
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
    return $resultRedirect;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your **Observer**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Customer\Observer;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;

class CustomerAccountEdited implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $customerRepository;
    protected $helper;
    protected $_objectManager = null;
    protected $resultRedirectFactory;
    protected $messageManager;
    protected $_redirect;
    protected $_actionFlag;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Vendor\Customer\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag
    ){
        $this->_request             = $request;
        $this->customerRepository   = $customerRepository;
        $this->helper               = $helper;
        $this->_objectManager       = $objectManager;
        $this->resultRedirectFactory= $resultRedirectFactory;
        $this->messageManager       = $messageManager;
        $this->_redirect = $redirect;
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
    }

    public function execute( \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer ){
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
            __("Success message")
        );
        $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        $this->_redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'checkout/cart');
        return $observer;
    }
}
```

Hope this will helpful to you!

Comment: Did you tried this solution ? and is this working or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Easily has done by Override the EditPost controller and set the redirect to checkout controller in the plugin

> Filepath: Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\EditPost">
    <plugin name="vendor_module_editpost" type="\Vendor\Module\Plugin\EditPost" sortOrder="1" />
  </type>
</config>
```

> Filepath: Vendor/Module/Plugin/EditPost.php:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class EditPost
{

    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
        $result)
    {
        $result->setPath('checkout'); // Change this to what you want
        return $result;
    }

}
```

**Note:Code tested**